# 301 Redirect of old url with parameters to a path without parametes

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need the following request :

```
http://somesite.com/home.php?action=page&page_id=9
```

to trigger a 301 redirect to :

```
http://somesite.com/a-new-page
```

Here's what I'm using but it isn't working.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=9$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ http://somesite.com/a-new-page? [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If the QUERY_STRING will always be the same you need to match it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=page&page_id=9$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home.php$ http://somesite.com/a-new-page? [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps.