# Redirect of URL with parameters to URL without -- plus Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have rebuilt a website that used some custom php to serve up individual store pages with urls like this:

```
http://thedomain.com/storedetails.php?storeNum=1
```

The new site is powered by Wordpress, and each individual store will live in a named subdirectory, like this:

```
http://thedomain.com/stores/gothamcity
```

I have been trying solutions I have found on stackoverflow that all seem to be variations on this: [301 Redirect of old url with parameters to a path without parametes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277154/301-redirect-of-old-url-with-parameters-to-a-path-without-parametes)

Here's an example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^storeNum=18$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/storedetails\.php$ http://www.thedomain.com/stores/gothamcity? [L,R=301]
```

But so far nothing works. I continue to get "page not found" 404 error pages in Wordpress.

My best guess is that something in Wordpress's part of the .htaccess is throwing this off? Here's what they include:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^storeNum=18$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^storedetails\.php http://www.thedomain.com/stores/gothamcity? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I suggest you use a RewriteMap though to map store numbers to names.

Comment: I'm going to try your answer now and see how it works. While I'm doing that, could you tell me what a RewriteMap is?

Comment: Your answer did indeed work! Can you explain to me what you did differently? What is that %{HTTP_Host} .* bit?

Comment: Glad to hear it works :) I don't think the HTTP_HOST thing is needed since it sounds like you're redirecting on the same host. I only added it because your earlier rule explicitly set the redirected host. I think the only thing different is the order of the rules. Also RewriteRule doesn't match the initial `/`.

Comment: A RewriteMap is where you use a file to map numbers to names, then rewrite URLs to replace numbers with names, much like what you want to do here. The map must be defined in httpd.conf or the virtualhost configuration, but you can use it in .htaccess. Look here for more details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html